# define constant using if isset

Tags: php, constants

I have an array of constants I'm using to populate an array of params. The code looks something like this:

```
define( 'variable_one', $_POST["variable_one"];
define( 'variable_two', $_POST["variable_two"];

$current_api_params->sVariableOne = variable_one;
$current_api_params->sVariabletwo = variable_two;
```

How do I set one of the constants through an if statement? The variables are coming from a form, and given the form options, variable_one, or two or any of the dozens I'm working with, might be a number of different names.

Do I just do something like

```
if ( isset($_POST["variable_one"] ) {
  define( 'variable_one', $_POST["variable_one"] );
}
elseif ( isset($_POST["variable_one_different_name"] ) {
  define( 'variable_one', $_POST["variable_one_different_name"] );
}
else {
  define( 'variable_one', '' );
}

$current_api_params->sVariableOne = variable_one;
```

If that's how it is done, is there a shorthand for it? All this typing is getting tedious!

Comment: Are you just asking, or did you try that and it didn't work?

Comment: I hadn't tried it yet. I just tried it and it works, but it presents problems due to having to then write if (isset()){} statements around the $params lines too. Like Don pointed out below, they aren't really constants, so there's no need to define them. I can just set the post variable into the array list using the conditional. I suppose the shorthand for the if statement is a Ternary operator, right? I'm going to go try to use the ternary operator without the else part attached and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and for loop

Somewhere along these lines (you might need to check some syntax error, as I'm typing this without any IDE/proper environment)

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST)
foreach ($keys as $keyItem)
{
    define($keyItem, $_POST[$keyItem]);
}
```

Though I'm not sure why constants are not constant at all ... but hey that's up to you to decide.

Comment: That won't work because they must have specific names to interact with the API and the form input name doesn't always match. You are right though, they aren't constants, and I'm pretty sure I can write the if statement around the $params line. Thanks for pointing that out, as I believe it solves the problem. I'm going to give it a shot today. A lot of the constants aren't actual constants, but because I inherited the project, I've just kept writing them as such in order to maintain uniformity with the previous code. There was too much to be worth going back and refactoring it. Thanks.